# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'. Why am I receiving this error?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping

I was able to successfully scrape this site but now it is not working correctly. I am receiving an error for the 'temperatures' variable now.

These variables work...

```
period_names = [item.find(class_='period-name').get_text() for item in items]

short_descriptions = [item.find(class_='short-desc').get_text() for item in items]
```

This variable used to work... now it does not.

```
temperatures = [item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]
```

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php? 
lat=34.05349000000007&lon=-118.24531999999999#.XV8stehKg2w')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
week = soup.find(id='seven-day-forecast-body')
items = (week.find_all(class_= 'tombstone-container'))

period_names = [item.find(class_='period-name').get_text() for item in 
items]
short_descriptions = [item.find(class_='short-desc').get_text() for item 
in items]
temperatures = [item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]

print(temperatures)
```

I expect the code to print out the temperatures for each day since it has worked in the past. Instead I am getting and AttributeError message:

```
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\giraffe\apps.py", line 97, 
in <listcomp>
    temperatures = [item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Comment: You're getting that error 'cause at some point `item.find(class_='temp')` is giving `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
temperatures = [item.find(class_='temp').get_text() if item.find(class_='temp') is not None else "" for item in items]
```

This will return an empty string if your lookup returns `None`

Comment: This worked out great...Thank you very much!

Comment: @AbleArcher Please accept the answer so future users know that this answer was correct.